# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.FileName.get' (CS0120)

Tags: c#

Whenever i try to run this, i get this error: 
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.FileName.get' (CS0120)

I am quite confused on how to fix as i have seen other forums but they do not share the same problem as me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }

    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu cMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem one = new MenuItem("test", new EventHandler(TestClick));
        cMenu.MenuItems.Add(one);
        Minecraft.ContextMenu = cMenu;
        //Minecraft.Image = new Bitmap(System.Configuration);
    }

    void newClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog gamedir = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (gamedir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try 
            {

            }

            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }

    void TestClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Minecraft.Image = new Bitmap(openFile.FileName);
        }

    }

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        Process.Start(@"D:\Games\Minecraft\Minecraft");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void Button3Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void Label1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void Dark_CrusadeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(@"D:\Games\Dark crusade\DarkCrusade.exe");
    }


    void Add_GameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int top = 60;
         int left = 405;

         for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
         {
            OpenFileDialog newgame = new OpenFileDialog();
            string FilePath = OpenFileDialog.FileName;

            if (newgame.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Top = top;
            button.Left = left;
            button.Height = 265;
            button.Width = 189;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            top += button.Height + 2;
            }

         }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Providing [MCVE] is very good step to finding solution (or at least to good question). Wall of code with whole bunch of empty methods is not *minimal* example.

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenFileDialog newgame = new OpenFileDialog();
string FilePath = OpenFileDialog.FileName;
```

You're referencing `OpenFileDialog` in a static context when accessing `FileName`; you need to use the `newgame` instance of `OpenFileDialog` in order to retrieve the FileName property:

```
OpenFileDialog newgame = new OpenFileDialog();
string FilePath = newgame.FileName;
```

Comment: I tried this out and it works. Thanks for helping me.